# Cannot complete this action creating view programatically

Tags: development

I am trying to create a view programatically to be used in an XSLTViewWebPart.
When I try to browse to the view I got this exception:

Cannot complete this action. Please try again.

I set the log to verbose in all categories, but there is nothing.

```
public static void CreateRequestDetailView(SPWeb sourceWeb, string listName, string viewName, string detailNameNorthSouth, string xslLink)
    {
        SPList sourceList = sourceWeb.GetSafeListByName(listName);

        SPView view = sourceList.GetViewByName(viewName);

        if(view != null) {
            sourceList.Views.Delete(view.ID);
        }

        StringCollection viewFields = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();            
        foreach (SPField field in sourceList.Fields)
        {
            viewFields.Add(field.StaticName);
        }

        string myquery = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/><Value Type=\"Number\">{SelectedID}</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";

        view = sourceList.Views.Add(viewName, viewFields, myquery, 1, false, false);
        view.ParameterBindings += @"<ParameterBinding Name='SelectedID' Location='None' DefaultValue='' />";
        view.XslLink = xslLink;
        view.Update();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the "Cannot complete this action" come up for two reasons.

First make sure that you have permission to view that area. I have two user profiles that I use one with access to all areas and one with limited access. When I test my new webparts in the limited user I sometimes forget that I do not have access to certain areas.

Second would be if for some reason the list page itself would need to be checked in or published. I have a lot of custom code in my masterpage and I get this error every time I make a change to it. I have to remember that I need to publish it so that it can be viewable.

I really can't see anything wrong with your code and from what you stated above it sounds like the issue is occuring before you actually call the function so I would have to say that one of the two above resolutions should work.